# As versões atuais do Java tem os pacotes para Servlet?

Tags: servlet

No computador da faculdade usei esse código para fazer a conexão do Java com a Web. Funcionou, porém em casa, tenho uma versão mais atual do Eclipse e o código se comportou de maneira diferente. Ele não reconhece o import javax.servlet. Com isso
fica com erro:

```
package br.edu.unicid.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import br.edu.unicid.bean.Aluno;
import br.edu.unicid.dao.AlunoDAO;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletAluno
 */
 @WebServlet("/ServletAluno")
public class ServletAluno extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // a variável cmd indica o tipo de ação - incluir, alterar, consulta.....
        String cmd = request.getParameter("cmd");
        // cria um objeto dao - CRUD
        AlunoDAO dao;
        // cria um objeto do tipo aluno
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        if (cmd != null) {
            try {
            // inicializa os atributos da classe Alunos

             aluno.setCaAluno(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtCa")));
             aluno.setNomeAluno(request.getParameter("txtNome"));
             aluno.setEmailAluno(request.getParameter("txtEmail"));
             aluno.setDtaNasc(request.getParameter("txtData"));
       aluno.setIdadeAluno(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtIdade")));

             aluno.setEndAluno(request.getParameter("txtEndereco"));
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
        }try {
            // cria a instancia do objeto dao
            dao = new AlunoDAO();
            RequestDispatcher rd = null;


            // incluir aluno
           if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("incluir")) {
                dao.salvar(aluno);

           }    
           // rd.forward(request,response);
          // executa a ação de direcionar para a página JSP  
     }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
}
```

}

Comment: Isso acontece porque na escola você deve estar usando Java EE e na sua casa deve estar usando Java SE.